# Update an attribute in DynamoDB if another attribute exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

In DynamoDB, is it possible to accomplish the following via an `UpdateItem` operation?

```
set attributeA to valueX if the attribute does not exist
set attributeB to valueX if attributeA exists
```

Both of these must be in the same `UpdateItem` operation. I'm aware of things like `attribute_not_exists` and `if_not_exists`, but I couldn't find an `if_exists` condition.

How can I accomplish the above task using the low-level APIs?

Comment: `DynamoDB also provides an attribute_exists function.` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html

Comment: That's correct, but how does that help in my case?

Comment: In the phrase "if the attribute does not exist" what do you mean? Which attribute? Do you mean the entire item?

Comment: I meant `attributeA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, you cannot in one `UpdateItem`.

You can fetch the item, modify it on the client, then push a new copy. Use optimistic locking to ensure the item wasn't modified in between.